# Is it possible to use native characters in subdomains?

Tags: dns, subdomain

Is it possible to use characters such as åäö in subdomains? I know you can use åäö in regular domains like http://åberg.se but can you do åäö.foo.se?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. You just have to Punycode the name and use that.

E.g. **åäö.foo.se** converts to **xn--4cab6c.foo.se** so just use those funny xn-prefixed names in DNS configurations.

Browsers supporting internationalized domain names should not care where you use non-ascii characters, as they should simply convert non-ascii input to Punycode and internally use the encoded names.